# laravel routes: changeing order of variables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to add two different routes to the same action in the controller, but I need to provide null value in the middle.

routes:

```
Route::get('post/get-ajax-posts/start/{start}/profile/{profileid}', 'PostController@getAjaxPosts');    
Route::get('post/get-ajax-posts/start/{start}/tag/{tagName}', 'PostController@getAjaxPosts');
```

controller:

```
public function getAjaxPosts(Request $request, $startRow, $profile = null, $tagName = null){}
```

I would like to provide $profile = null in the second route but I get $profile = {tagName}

How can I do that?

The only thing i have found is to add in the controller:

```
      $routeParameters = $this->getRouter()->getCurrentRoute()->parameters();
      if(isset($routeParameters['tagName']) && $routeParameters['tagName']){
            $tagName = $routeParameters['tagName'];
            $profile = null;
        }
```

Is there any easier way?

Comment: you can use `?` for optional parameter, like `'user/{name?}'`

Comment: imho they seems two different routes with two different function call. If the logic is the same you can have a function that retrieve params and call the  other function. I dont think optional params is a applicable solution to the routes as you wrote them.

Comment: Can you post your whole controller method as there is probably a cleaner way to achieve what you're after? Also, do you *have* to use the same route i.e. you're adding to existing code?

Comment: Of course I can do it in few different ways and probably I will do it, but the question is, is there a solution to inject this null value in the routing?

Answer (score 0):

its very simple bro

inside the public function get all your route variable

```
public function getAjaxPosts(Request $request){
$startRow   =  $request['startRow'];
$profile    = null ; 
$tagName    = null ;
}
```

Comment: It work's this way for POST method, for GET you have to call

`$routeParameters = $this->getRouter()->getCurrentRoute()->parameters();`